# HP PAVILION DV7 Oveheating and loud fan running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, overheating, fan

I have a HP PAVILION DV7 Notebook with 8GB RAM, 2.0 GHz Core i7 CPU, and 2 graphic cards: Intel HD, and AMD Radeon and I used to have some problems with overheating and loud fan when doing heavy stuff on Windows but I've never encountered it with only 2 tabs of Firefox and a terminal opened, like I do on Ubuntu 16.04. I was expecting to have a more reliable laptop after installing Linux but some problems I havent had before are popping up and I dont know what to do. To mention I've cleaned the fan a week ago but still, didnt do the job.
Should I change the distro? or Should I do something that I havent tried yet.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wrong driver woking in background.

1) make sure you have all the required drivers.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Cross verify that required drivers are installed and visible in system > Additional Drivers.

If you failed to find Intel HD or  AMD Radeon drivers follow these articles:

https://www.techzim.co.zw/2017/06/tuning-intel-graphics-card-ubuntu-16-04/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

2) In windows, it switches automatically between  between Intel HD and AMD Radeon. But in Ubuntu, user have to manually select them as per their requirement (In system > Additional Drivers)and need to reboot the system.

AMD Radeon is a powerful graphic card but don't save power and causes system heat problem. I will suggest you to keep in  Intel HD.

Intel HD is powerful enough to handle any thing. Only change to AMD Radeon if you need powerful graphic card support like for software 3D modeling or graphic designing or heavy graphic supported gaming.

While using AMD Radeon, to avoid overheating problem, you have to manually optimize system clock speed according to your system. See this below article:

[Change AMD Radeon GPU Core/Memory Clock Frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990462/change-amd-radeon-gpu-core-memory-clock-frequency)

You may also require hot air exhaust to handle system heating.